# Proof: Convergence in Distribution implying Convergence in Probability (Special Case)

Tags: statistics

I am having a hard time understanding a proof.

The theorem says

$$X_n \rightarrow_D b \space \text{then} \space X_n \rightarrow_p b $$
where b is a constant.

A part of the proof says

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} Pr[|X_n-b|\le \epsilon]
& = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}F_{X_n}(b + \epsilon) - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{X_n}((b-\epsilon)-0)\\
& = 1 - 0\\
& = 1
\end{align}$$

Where $F_{X_n}$ is the cdf of the iid $X_i$ s.

I understand the big picture where why we want to prove that 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}Pr[|X_n-b|\le \epsilon] =1$$
and I also see that the expansion of the absolute value sign gives the expression in the first row.

But I have no idea why each of those expressions are equal to 1 and 0, respectively.

I think I am not really understanding what convergence in distribution really means.

I only know that the limit of the moment generating function simplifies to something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_{X_n} (x) \to F_b(x)$ whenever $F_b$ is continuous at $x$. [Here $F_b(x)=1$ if $x \geq b$ and $0$ of $x <b$]. Note that $F_b$ is continuous at all points except $b$. Since $b+\epsilon >b$ and $F_b(b+\epsilon) =1$ you see that the first term is $1$. Similarly for the second term.

Comment: Please give me a moment, I will try to understand it ... I guess what I don't understand is, that a cdf is a constant.  How does that work?

Comment: In other words, how do we know that $F_b(x)=1$ when $x \ge b$ ? Hold on, I found https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2271088/what-does-it-mean-to-get-the-cdf-of-a-constant-variable

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to understand it :)  I guess it is sometimes difficult to realize that there are people like me who doesn't understand that $Pr[X \le x] = Pr[b \le x]$ is what $F_b(x)$ really means.